# what is the Issue with this code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
 class CommentsController < ApplicationController
   def users_comments 
     posts = Post.all
     comments = posts.map(&:comments).flatten
     @user_comments = comments.select do |comment|
       comment.author.username == params[:username]
     end
   end 
 end
```

Comment: `end` is missing for `do` i think

Comment: @Sachin: Why don't you post the error message?

Comment: We don't know. Why don't you tell us, so we can help you fix it? What *is* the issue? Do you get an error message? If yes, what is it? Do you get a warning message? If yes, what is it? Is the code too slow? If yes, how fast does it need to be and how fast is it now? Does it use too much memory? If yes, how much can it use, and how much does it use now? Is it not maintainable? Does it give the wrong result? If yes, what result do you expect (and why), and what result do you get, and why is that result not the one you are expecting? Please, give a complete and precise description of what the …

Comment: … code is supposed to do (including any and all corner cases, special cases, edge cases, and exceptions), and why, what it actually does, any and all error messages and warnings you are getting, as well as a set of examples of inputs and desired outputs that exhaustively exhibits all the edge cases, corner cases, special cases, and exceptions. Or, in short, please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**try** :

This can all be avoided by changing the first line in the method to:

```
posts = Post.includes(comments: [:user]).all
```

like

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def users_comments 

    posts = Post.includes(comments: [:user]).all
    comments = posts.map(&:comments).flatten
    @user_comments = comments.select do |comment|
    comment.author.username == params[:username]
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `end` for `do` is missing in code and also you need to include the `comments` and `author` associations to avoid n+1 queries.

```
posts = Post.includes(comments: :author)
```

So the code will look like

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def users_comments 
    posts = Post.includes(comments: :author)
    comments = posts.map(&:comments).flatten
    @user_comments = comments.select do |comment|
      comment.author.username == params[:username]
    end
  end
end
```